# One handed Dvorak on Linux/X11

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xorg, dvorak

I can change to standard dvorak by running `setxkbmap dvorak`, how do I change to right handed Dvorak, is there a new keymap I need to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For right-handed Dvorak try:

```
setxkbmap us dvorak-r
```